# Deploying Rails 3 Application on GoDaddy Linux Dedicated Server

Tags: linux, deployment, godaddy, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a  Linux Dedicated Server hosted through godaddy. How would I go about deploying a rails 3 application on this server? I currently do not have rails installed on the server and I have no clue where to start. The GoDaddy Rep said to install Rails through ssh but thats all he could provide me with.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Do you have Fedora, CentOS, or Ubuntu?

Comment: Mike, I am using CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

After you are logged in as root you should be able to run the following to get Rails installed and working.

Run the following commands on the server:

```
yum install gcc-c++ glibc-devel httpd-devel automake autoconf libtool libtool-libs

cd /usr/local/src

wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ruby-1.8.5.tar.gz

tar xzvf ruby-1.8.5.tar.gz

cd ruby-1.8.5

./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make instal

cd ..

wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/28174/rubygems-0.9.5.tgz

tar xvzf rubygems-0.9.5.tgz

cd rubygems-0.9.5

ruby setup.rb

cd ..

gem install rails

wget http://fastcgi.com/dist/fcgi-2.4.0.tar.gz

tar -xvzf fcgi-2.4.0.tar.gz

cd fcgi-2.4.0

./configure && make && make install

cd ..

wget http://fastcgi.com/dist/mod_fastcgi-2.4.2.tar.gz

tar -xvzf mod_fastcgi-2.4.2.tar.gz

cd mod_fastcgi-2.4.2

cp Makefile.AP2 Makefile

vi Makefile
```

Change:

```
top_dir = /usr/local/apache2
```

To:

```
top_dir = /usr/lib/httpd
```

Then:

```
make && make install

cd ..

gem install fcgi

gem install mysql
```

(NOTE: If this fails, do this: `gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-include=/usr/include/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib/mysql` )

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/fastcgi.conf

User apache

Group apache

LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    FastCgiWrapper on
    FastCgiConfig -idle-timeout 900
    FastCgiIpcDir /tmp/fastcgi_ipc/
    AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi .rb
</IfModule>


mkdir /tmp/fastcgi_ipc

chown -R apache.apache /tmp/fastcgi_ipc

chmod -R 755 /tmp/fastcgi_ipc

service httpd graceful
```

Comment: I'm stuck on this part - unable to edit the file:

wget http://fastcgi.com/dist/mod_fastcgi-2.4.2.tar.gz 

tar -xvzf mod_fastcgi-2.4.2.tar.gz

cd mod_fastcgi-2.4.2

cp Makefile.AP2 Makefile

vi Makefile

Change:

top_dir = /usr/local/apache2

to

top_dir = /usr/lib/httpd

make && make install

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you try to run each of those commands.  Each line is a separate command.

Answer (score -3):

Here are some pointers:

http://ihassin.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/setting-up-a-rails-server-on-a-godaddy-vps/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This ensures that the answer will remain available even if the link goes dead. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.